What causes and how can I fix the Spark error - FetchFailedException
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ShuffleMapStage 18 ($anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$5 at LexicalThreadLocal.scala:63) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason:
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException. 


..............
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection from /XX.XXX.XX.XXX:4048 closed

This job takes up a lot of resources and fails after 6 hours, I havent done any change yet, my plan is to test using lower partitions, remove spark.driver.maxResultSize 2g,   spark.driver.memory 80g from the custom spark config that were passed to the job.

Please provide example code or execution plan that you’re trying out. It could be that you’re trying to collect results and overwhelming the driver

the fact that the job takes up a lot of resources and fails after 6 hours is probably a sign that you're exceeding the memory but we either need more in depth error logs or a physical plan so we can get a better idea about what's happening
